# Cannot read property 'url' of undefined node

Tags: javascript, express

I'm trying to build a youtube video downloader using node, express and ytdl-core, but I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined". The video is downloaded, but the file is corrupted, before adding the render, the download was ok

This is my js:

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const { url } = req.query;
  ytdl.getInfo(url).then((info) => {
    let name = info.videoDetails.title;
    let thumbnail = info.videoDetails.thumbnail.thumbnails[4].url;
    
    res.header("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="${name}.mp4"`);
    res.render("index.ejs", { name, thumbnail });

    return ytdl(url).pipe(res);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you get from the call is not formatted the way your code expects. Inspect the actual result.

Comment: i'm new to express (and node in general) so I don't know why when I use res.render the url becomes undefined